# No me coge bien la fecha de la base de datos

Tags: java

Tengo hecho un método que se conecta con la base de datos y devuelve toda la información de la playlist. El problema está en que al ejecutarlo, no funciona bien y devuelve un "java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" sobre la línea 184.
Le he puesto un punto de depuración. Y me he dado cuenta de que falla, porque el campo que devuelve (el de fecha, está a null). Mi pregunta es, por que no devuelve correctamente el campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
/**
 * método que devuelve las playlist de un usuario
 * @return ArrayList de playslist de un usuario
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public ArrayList<PlayList> getBiblioteca() throws SQLException {//método que devuelve un arraylist de arraylist
     ArrayList<PlayList> biblioteca=new ArrayList<PlayList>();
     //Aqui lo que hay que hacer es un select de playslist where usuario = this.email
    Statement smt = ConexionBD.conectar();
    try {   
        ResultSet consulta = smt.executeQuery("select * from playlist where usuario_email = '"+this.email+"'");
        while(consulta.next()) {
            PlayList listas=new PlayList();
            listas.setFoto(consulta.getString("foto"));
            listas.setNombre(consulta.getString("nombre"));
            listas.usuario=new Usuario(consulta.getString("usuario_email"));
            listas.fechaCreacion=consulta.getTimestamp("fechaincorporacion").toLocalDateTime();
            biblioteca.add(listas);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UsuarioIncorrectoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ConexionBD.desconectar();
    return biblioteca;
}
```

PD: Las fechas, se insertan correctamente en la bd. Este es el constructor.

```
public PlayList(String foto, String nombre, Usuario usuario, LocalDateTime fechaCreacion) throws SQLException {
        super();
        if (foto==null) {//compruebo si el campo foto está null
            foto="./fotos/notaMusical.png";
        }
        Statement smt = ConexionBD.conectar();
        if(smt.executeUpdate(
                "insert into playlist values('"+foto.replace((char) 92, '/')+"','"+nombre+"','"+usuario.getEmail()+"','"+fechaCreacion.format(formatoFechaHora)+"')"
                )>0) {
        }
        this.setNombre(nombre);//nombre de la lista
        this.setFoto(foto);
        this.usuario=usuario;//el usuario
        this.fechaCreacion=fechaCreacion;
        
        ConexionBD.desconectar();
    }
```

Comment: Intenta con : `listas.fechaCreacion=consulta.getDate("fechaincorporacion").toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: ya lo he corregido, era usuario el que fallaba. Usaando el this.email= consulta.getString("usuario_email"); se soluciona